# Entity framework, Row Limiting Operation Without OrderBy Warning

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-core

i am making rest api in ASP.NET CORE using MySQL db. In one of my repositories i am getting, filtering, paging and sorting data. Although i get a WARN message: __
queryObj__Categorie.. uses a row limitating operation (Skip/Take) which may lead to unpredictable results. So my question is, what kind of unpredictable results may i get with the following code???

```
public async Task<QueryResult<User>> GetAll(UserQuery queryObj)
        var query = context.users
           .Include(users=> users.Category)
           .Include(users=> users.Tags)
           .Include(users=> users.Localization)
           .AsQueryable();

        if (queryObj.Categories.Length > 0)
             query = query.Where(v => queryObj.Categories.Contains(v.Category.Name));
        if (queryObj.Localizations.Length > 0)
             query = query.Where(v => queryObj.Localizations.Contains(v.Localization.Id));

        int usersCount = query.Count();
        //only orders when there is specific value set in queryObj
        query = query.ApplyOrdering(queryObj, COLUMNS_MAP);
        query = query.ApplyPaging(queryObj);
        var users = await query.ToListAsync();
        var queryResult = new QueryResult<Users>();
        queryResult.items = users;
        queryResult.itemsCount = usersCount ;
        return queryResult;
}
```

My paging extension method:

```
public static IQueryable<T> ApplyPaging<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, IQueryObject queryObj) 
{
    return query.Skip((queryObj.Page - 1) * queryObj.PageSize).Take(queryObj.PageSize);
}
```

Comment: Let's say I had 10 kids. Page size is 2. You ask for the second page. I decide to order the kids by Age, and I return them. Then you ask for the third page. This time I decide to order them alphabetically, and I return them. Then you ask for the fourth page. This time I decide to order them randomly, and I return them. This is what the warning is telling you - unless you are explicit about the order, the database can return any data it wants and legally meet your request. Paging, **by definition**, requires explicit ordering to be useful / reliable.

Comment: Thanks, i think thats pretty explanatory ;)

Comment: In addition to mjwills comment, regardless of paging, if you do not specify an order by clause, you have no guarantees regarding the order of results for multiple executions of your query.

Comment: I was doing `OrderBy` after `Skip/Take`, so this warning made me realize the difference.

Comment: Same as @Jeppe. In my case, I had to re-write the query from context.Data.Take(X).OrderBy(x => x.Field) to context.Data.OrderBy(x => x.Field).Take(X)